# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method in c#

Tags: c#, entity

Please tell me why I am seeing this error:

**LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method**

On this code:

```
var shopCom = _entities.ShoppingComments.LastOrDefault(
XX => XX.UserId == obj.UserId &&
XX.ShoppingScoreTypeId ==obj.TypeId &&
XX.WhichId == obj.Id &&
XX.CommentDate ==objShoppingComment.CommentDate &&
XX.Commnet ==objShoppingComment.Commnet);
```

Comment: What is XX? What is obj? Where do you use shopCom? At what line does the error appear?

Comment: ShoppingComment objShoppingComment ; PostCommentDto obj;

Comment: It was about comparing comment(string), XX.Commnet ==objShoppingComment.Commnet and if I delete it, the code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550(v=vs.110).aspx), `Last` and `LastOrDefault` methods are unsupported.

If you expect zero or one records, simple replace the `LastOrDefault` with `FirstOrDefault`.

Otherwise use something like this:

```
var shopCom = _entities.ShoppingComments
    .Where(XX => XX.UserId == obj.UserId &&
        XX.ShoppingScoreTypeId ==obj.TypeId &&
        XX.WhichId == obj.Id &&
        XX.CommentDate ==objShoppingComment.CommentDate &&
        XX.Commnet ==objShoppingComment.Commnet)
    .OrderByDescending(XX => XX.SomeField)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: It was about comparing comment(string), XX.Commnet ==objShoppingComment.Commnet and if I delete it, the code works

Comment: I doubt. Except you are using EF Core, do you?

Comment: @SurenSrapyan I don't see how the link you provides relates to the issue. First, here we are speaking about `Queryable.LastOrDefault`. Second, OP stated **LINQ to Entities** in the question, and the link I've provided in the answer clearly states that `LastOrDefault` is not supported.

Comment: yes I am :| what should I do ?, also FirstOrDefault doesn't help me

Comment: @ara You should have included that in the question. There is a big difference between EF versions. And EF Core (especially RC1) as unreleased software is buggy and unstable. I would suggest you updating the question and post and accept self answer if you manged to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Linq to Entities is translated to SQL under the hood, so i think the problem is in the LastOrDefault, reverse the enumerable and use FirstOrDefault.

Comment: It was about comparing comment(string), XX.Commnet ==objShoppingComment.Commnet and if I delete it, the code works, but the question is why I can't compare string :|